# Date Arithmetic with SQL and DB2 for i

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to run a SQL query that will update information in a specific table.  the problem I am running into is that I need the query to pull today's date, for whatever the date may be when the query is run, and then only pull records going back to years.  I then want it to return an `AVG` of the CUR_CASH_UNITS over that two year time period.  I have tried DATEDIFF and DATEADD and those do not appear to work with the system I have because it returns a *libl error.  Here is what I have:

```
Select  Month,
    SSSALESNAM,
    CAT,
    Sum(Units) as Units     
From    DW****.******EG
Inner Join  (Select CAT,
                STORE,
                MONTH(DATE) As Month,
                Sum(CUR_CASH_UNITS) As Units
         From   DW*******.****AT        
         Inner Join (Select CAT,
                            CATNUM
                     From   DW****.*****ST) As Category_List             
        On         DW*******.****AT.CATEGORY_NUMBER=Category_List.CATNUM
        --Where  (((CUR_CASH_UNITS.MONTH(DATE)) Between MONTH(DATE) And (MONTH(DATE)-24MONTH))
        Group by Cat,
                 Store,
                 MONTH(DATE)) As Cash_Units

On          DW****.******EG.SSSTR=Cash_Units.STORE           
Group By    Month,
        SSSALESNAM,
        CAT
Order By    Month,
        SSSALESNAM
```

The section above that is commented out is just one of my attempts to get the date arithmetic to work.  With the `Where` statement commented out the query executed correctly.  The date column in my table is labeled as DATE with a format of YYYY-MM-DD.  Kind of new to SQL so I apologize in advance if it is something simple that I am overlooking.

Comment: Although, please don't ever use `BETWEEN`, even if it does work for actual date columns - you never know when the column might turn into a timestamp.  Actually, it's usually the wrong way to 'think' about dates (as in, how they're dealt with conceptually), especially for timestamp stuff.  Which is why you should use a lower-bound inclusive (`>=`), upper-bound exclusive (`<`) range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a `where` clause like the following:

```
where "date" between current date - 2 years and current date
```

You need the double quotes because `date` is a reserved word.  The rest is just for getting a date in the past two years.

Comment: [DB2 for IBM i 7.1 Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp)

Comment: If you give columns more descriptive names (eg. SalesDate) this will help you avoid accidentally using a reserved word, among other benefits.