# Getting derived column from database | SQL query | DB2 SystemDate

Tags: sql, db2

My table is `PRODUCTINFO`:

```
Column name : product_name | launch_date
Sample Date : product1       2017-01-20
```

I need a SQL query to decide if the product is newly launched or not.

Business rule :

```
if (launch_date - currentdate < 0 && currentdate - launch_date < 90) 
    newly_launched = 'YES'
else 
    newly_launched = 'NO'
```

where currentdate is today's date.

SQL query I am witting is like :

```
SELECT launch_date, X as newly_launched 
FROM PRODUCTINFO 
WHERE product_name = 'product1'
```

I am not able to figure out correct replacement of 'X' in my query for desired result.

Problem I am facing is using currentdate and if else block in my query

Please help.

One way to get currentdate in DB2 using following query :

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDD')
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Still not sure how to use this with my if else scenario.

Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320057) don't solve my problem as this scenario is if-else based.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or DB2? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: removed MySQL, MS SQL they were default recommended tags

Comment: Great! (Those tag suggestions cause a lot of inconsistent tagging...)

Comment: Your logic is not clear: `launch_date - current_date > 0` means `launch_date` is _after_ `current_date`, therefore `current_date - launch_date < 90` will _always_ be true. And yes, it's `current_date`, not `currentdate`.

Comment: @mustaccio :
1. yes this should be `launch_date - currentdate < 0`  (modified).
2. currentdate is today's date. 
So, I did not understand your 2nd point : `And yes, it's current_date, not currentdate` . Could you please elaborate.

Comment: The name of the special register containing the current date value in DB2 is `current_date`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date Arithmetic with SQL and DB2 for i](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320057/date-arithmetic-with-sql-and-db2-for-i)

Answer (score 1):

use TIMESTAMPDIFF with 16 as first parameter for count number days  between 2 timestamps, for more detail look [here](http://www.volubis.fr/bonus/sql_memo.htm)

try this

```
select launch_date, 
case when TIMESTAMPDIFF( 16, cast(cast(launch_date as timestamp) - current timestamp as char(22))) >0 and 
 TIMESTAMPDIFF( 16, cast(cast(launch_date as timestamp) - current timestamp as char(22))) <90 then 'YES' else 'NO' end newly 
from PRODUCTINFO
WHERE product_name = 'product1'
```

Comment: can you please explain this line:
`16, cast(cast(launch_date as timestamp) - current timestamp as char(22))`

Comment: 16 is Days. but remaining ?

Answer (score -1):

simply use datediff function in a case syntax, I hope it could help!

```
SELECT launch_date,
        case
            when DATEDIFF(day,launch_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 0 AND 90 then 'YES'
            else 'NO'
            end AS newly_launched
FROM PRODUCTINFO
WHERE product_name = 'product1'
```

in case you want to do it for all your records:

```
SELECT launch_date,
        case
            when DATEDIFF(day,launch_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 0 AND 90 then 'YES'
            else 'NO'
            end AS newly_launched
FROM PRODUCTINFO
```

Comment: getting Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=DAY, DRIVER=3.61.86
SQLState:  42703
ErrorCode: -206
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-206;42703;DAY, DRIVER=3.61.86
SQLState:  56098
ErrorCode: -727

Comment: doesn't work on DB2, datediff is for sql server, and he want >0, between include 0 and 90 values too